# Third level domain - howto

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

I'm a web developer and I've started admininstrating a small VPS for hosting some very small websites. For testing pourpose we need to create a third level domain, but I'm not sure about how to configure it. The server is running Debian stable with apache2.
I've added a virtual host to create a third level domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thirdlevel.servername.foo
    DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root
    # some other apache config
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, in the control panel of my ISP (where I bought the domain) I've put those parameter for DNS configuration, and I have no idea if this is correct or not:

```
record type: A
name: servername.com.
value: 12.34.56.789 (real IP here, of course)

record type: A
name: www
value: 12.34.56.789

record type: CNAME
name: thirdlevel.servername.foo.
value: servername.foo
```

after some hours the last rule (which is the one i'm not sure about) was marked "active" but I still cannot access my website pointing thirdlevel.servername.foo
thnks

Alessandro

Comment: It is very difficult to debug a DNS problem when you hide the real names. We cannot even test, so all the answers you will get are only guesses.

Comment: sry, I've found out that the problem was caused by a conflict in the zone config. now, It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You appear to have `servername.com` and `servername.foo` in the same zone. There should only be one domain per zone.
2. If you just forgot to change the first .com to .foo, then `thirdlevel.servername.foo.` should just be `thirdlevel`
3. For the value of `thirdlevel`, you need a `.` on the end, or it will append the origin for you (assuming the zone file starts with `$ORIGIN servername.foo.`).

If you have access to the text of the zone file, instead of the usual annoying HTML form that most registrars provide, you want something like the following:

```
$ORIGIN servername.foo.
$TTL 14400
@       86400   IN      SOA     YOUR.NS1.GOES.HERE.      your.email.with.at.replaced.by.dot.comcast.net.   (
                                        201009091812 ;Serial Number
                                        86400 ;refresh
                                        7200 ;retry
                                        3600000 ;expire
                                        86400 ;minimum
)
                86400   IN      NS      YOUR.NS1.GOES.HERE.
                86400   IN      NS      YOUR.NS2.GOES.HERE.
                14400   IN      A       123.45.67.89
www             14400   IN      A       123.45.67.89
thirdlevel      14400   IN      CNAME   @
```

The @ gets replaced by whatever $ORIGIN is set to, so you don't have to keep retyping it. I am curious why you can't just use another A record for `thirdlevel`.

Comment: I'm completely noob about DNS managing, so I tought a good point was to use CNAME. Now I know I must use A record for third level. I only have access to HTML form, so I must use it. The .org/.foo problem is not the point (in fact it's just a fake server name, not the actual one :D)

Answer (score 0):

It might take sometime for DNS changes to replicate everywhere.
Check if you can resolve the new CNAME already.
The apache configuration looks good so far.

Answer (score -2):

Your Apache2 is configured correctly, but in your domain's DNS you are missing CNAME record for *any* third level domain

```
value:   *.yourdomain.com
type:    CNAME
target:  yourdomain.com
```

Comment: The accepted answer is substantially better and doesn't imply that you must add wildcard CNAMEs and also points out that CNAMES aren't even necessary.